# add item button hide django admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline

I have the following django admin inline

```
class PostInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Post
    form = PostForm
    extra = 1
```

but I need that is not visible button to add another item, but if the additional item is respected (extra=1)

add max_num=0, delete the add another item button, but also takes the additional record to add the extra=1

I hope your help.

Comment: Did you try setting `max_num=1` instead?

Comment: @Ngenator yes, I've tried but shows no further record, but if you delete the button to add another item.